# Finding averages by key from a csv in python

Tags: python, csv, average

I have a simple 2 column csv and need to find the average per key
i.e.
input csv

```
A,2
B,3
A,1
C,2
B,2
D,4
C,2
```

required output

```
{'A': 1.5, 'B': 2.5, 'C': 2, 'D': 4}
```

---

Code thus far:

```
pythoncsvfile = open("data.csv") 
csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') 
for row in csv_reader: 
    print (row[0],row[1])
```

Comment: That's a good, clear problem statement.  Now, try to write some code to implement it.  If you get stuck, tell us what you're stuck on and why.

Comment: Do you have `pandas`?

Comment: Have you considered what a suitable container data type might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option A**

Using `csv`

```
import csv
import collections

out = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        out[line[0]].append(int(line[1]))

for k in out: 
    out[k] = sum(out[k]) / len(out[k])

print(dict(out))

{'A': 1.5, 'B': 2.5, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 4.0}
```

---

**Option B**

Using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, names=['Key', 'Value'])
out = df.groupby('Key').mean()

print(out.Value.to_dict())

{'A': 1.5, 'B': 2.5, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 4.0}
```

Comment: Nice solution, though I wonder why you set `as_index=False`.  If you don't do that, you can then say `out.Value.to_dict()` to get the format OP requested.

Comment: @JohnZwinck The `Key` column becomes the index. I don't like how that looks. Really, that's all it is. :p

Comment: @JohnZwinck But that's a nice idea :) Thanks.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks. I opted for option A and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @user8420144 Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the following piece of code:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict()

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for index, value in content:
        if ( not data.has_key(index) ):
            #initialize
            data[index] = {'times':1, 'total':float(value)}
        else:
            #index already present
            data[index] = {'times': data[index]["times"]+1, 'total':data[index]["total"]+float(value)}

def average(data):
    results = OrderedDict()

    for index, values in data.iteritems():
        results[index] = values["total"]/values["times"]

    return results

print average(data)
```

## Example result with your data:

```
OrderedDict([('A', 1.5), ('B', 2.5), ('C', 2.0), ('D', 4.0)])
```

HTH